# Get file name when downloading file

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

Here's my action...

```
[HttpGet]
public object Download()
{
    return File("file.png", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "HiMum.png");
}
```

In the browser...

```
axios({

            url: AppPath + 'download/',
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob'
        })
        .then(response => {



            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers));

            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');

            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');

            link.click();

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
```

The trace only shows.. .

```
{"content-type":"application/octet-stream"}
```

How do I get the filename? I've tried adding...

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename=HiMum.png");
```

.. in the action.

Comment: In your JS, you should be able to access the headers on the `response` variable. Access the `Content-Disposition` header, and parse out the filename from that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The code already attempts this and when specifying "Content-Disposition" directly it's undefined.

Comment: Hi, interesting, this might have some additional info https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25715985/revisions

Comment: What do you mean it's undefined?

Comment: In Javascript, undefined is the value you get when you access a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

Server:

```
[HttpGet("Download")]
public object Download()
{
    return File("file.png", "application/octet-stream", "HiMum.png");
}
```

Client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        axios({
            url: 'download/',
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob'
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers));
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];
                console.log(disposition);

                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                }
                console.log(filename);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                link.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
    });
</script>
```